# Downloaded csv does not contain the whole post body

Tags: support, data-explorer

I use the following query to download a post from stack exchange database. The query results show the exact body as the post. However, the CSV file downloaded from the page only contains the first paragraph of the post body, so most of the body content is missing. Is there any issue about the CSV download link? Thanks.

https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1139722

or

SELECT p.id, p.Body FROM Posts p Where p.id = 55183861

Comment: I downloaded the CSV but it is complete. How are you viewing it?

Comment: I was using Excel, which turns out to be the problem. When I use email or cat, it is complete. Thanks @PirosaysReinstateMonica